# Android Studio me pide desinstalar una app que no tengo instalada INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android-studio, apk

Soy nuevo en Android Studio, y tengo un Xiaomi Redmi 9.

Apenas estaba instalando Android Studio y para finalizar trate de crear una aplicación de prueba "Empty Activity". No modifique nada más.

Sin embargo, al tratar de instalar dicha app, se me olvido habilitar la instalación por USB, por lo que me dio un error y no se instalo nada. Ya después de habilitarlo volví a intentarlo, pero ahora Android Studio me lanza advertencias de que dicha app ya esta instalada.

Me da el error `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE`

¿Realmente se instalo algo?
¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este error? 
¿O puedo simplemente ignorarlo e intentar hacer otra app de prueba con otro nombre?

Comment: Hola, aumenta el valor de versionCode y trata de subirla a tu dispositivo nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si obtienes el error `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` significa que efectivamente tienes instalada una versiòn de la aplicaciòn pero tratas de instalar una nueva versiòn que tiene una versiòn menor (`versionCode` menor).

Lo que puedes realizar es alguno de estos 3 puntos:

- Ubicar la app instalada y desinstalarla.
- Modificar el `versionCode` de la versiòn a instalar con un valor mayor y eso provocarà que actualice la aplicaciòn instalada.
- Crear otra aplicaciòn con otro "application id".

Te sugiero revisar:

[Establece la versión de tu app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning?hl=es-419)